# Azure AAD and Graph API: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Context: I've a console app which wants to use Graph API to talk to AAD to check if a particular userId exists in the tenant or not.

I've been following the guidelines here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?view=graph-rest-1.0

I'm able to generate a token using this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id=x
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret=x
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

But when I call the graph API I get this ERROR:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/12345678-73a6-4952-a53a-e9916737ff7f
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "x",
            "date": "x"
        }
    }
}
```

My AAD App has all the permissions from:

```
1. Microsoft Graph
2. Windows Azure Active Directory
```

I tried changing the scope to

```
scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.read
```

But this is the error I get while generating token:

```
The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read is not valid.
```

I've tried combinations of "User.Read", "User.Basic.Read", etc. but nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason why this is not working is because the permission which you have configured your app registration to *require* have not actually been *granted* by an administrator of your organization.

In your code, your app is authenticating as an application *only*. There is no signed-in user involved, and it requires your app to use and keep confidential a key used to authenticate (the `client_secret` parameter).

In this scenario, requesting the scope `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` is the correct approach. What you're saying to Azure AD is: "please provide an access token for all the application permissions this app has been granted". Requesting the scope `https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read` is not the correct approach because there is no *application* permission with that name.

Answer (score 0):

Does the app you created have delegated permissions or application permissions to that scope?

Most likely the former. Delegated permissions don’t apply to client credentials flow.

Comment: Is this still true? I do have one app that has gotten several user permissions delegated to it. Among this the `offline_access` permission. Which afaik means the app can access the permitted user resources itself without user activity. In that scenario I am trying to get an access_token for the app using the client_id and client_secret. But I am getting errors...